# Jqplot - Algorithm used to calculate ticks

Tags: algorithm, jqplot

Can i know what algorithm jqplot uses to calculate the tick values?
It seems to use only the maximum and minimum data values as input to calculate the ticks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As described [in the docs](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.Properties), you can customize axis in several ways.

a. To change axis range and padding, you can use these options:

- `autoscale`: setting this to `false` turns off autoscaling
- `min`/`max`: sets minimum/maximum axis value
- `pad`/`padMin`/`padMax`: defines padding around min/max value
- `numberTicks`: number of ticks to show
- `tickInterval`: interval between two ticks (mutually exclusive with `numberTicks`)

b. Or, you can specify custom exact tick position as you like:

- `ticks`: either an array of values, or an array of `[value, label]` pairs